# how to show <p> by id when hovering over an <img> with an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="ico/plaster.png" id="img-plaster" ><br>Plaster</li>
      <li>as above 2...</li>
      <li>as above 3...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <p id="plaster-nfo" style="display:none">plaster etc</p>
    <p>as above 2</p>
    <p>as above test 3 not hidden</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#img-plaster:hover #plaster-nfo {
display: block;
}
```

I'm trying to display a `<p>` line of text with an id when an image with a different id is hovered over, this `<p>` will show further information when displayed about the topic the image hints towards.

If I should not be using css and using jquery/javascript or other please advise, but it must be mobile friendly.

I have a few `<p>`'s where all are hidden (`display:none`), apart from the last to make sure the `<p>`'s are in the right place.  However the CSS code as detailed is not working, therefore I must have something wrong or that it's not suitable for the task.

Comment: With your current structure this is not possible with CSS.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this in jquery/javascript etc to make this work?  Seems the suggestions so far have been to restructure the layout of the page, which is not what I'm wanting to do... any further thoughts/suggestions please?

Comment: Check some of the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

li p {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

li:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/201/" alt="" />
    <p>Text to show</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/199/" alt="" />
    <p>Text to show</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="" />
    <p>Text to show</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqEXWE

Mobile-friendly, and no need for javascript to achieve this :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
$("#img-plaster").mouseover(function(){
        $("#plaster-nfo").show();
    });
```

Comment: This solution will require the developer/cms to update both the HTML and javascript to make the hover work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for hover effect then use this

**[hover jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)**

```
$( "#img-plaster" ).hover(
  function() {
    $('#plaster-nfo').show();
  }, function() {
    $('#plaster-nfo').hide();
  }
);
```

Demo is here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#img-plaster" ).hover(
  function() {
    $('#plaster-nfo').show();
  }, function() {
    $('#plaster-nfo').hide();
  }
);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClUhe.jpg?s=32&g=1" id="img-plaster" ><br>Plaster</li>
      <li>as above 2...</li>
      <li>as above 3...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <p id="plaster-nfo" style="display:none">plaster etc</p>
    <p>as above 2</p>
    <p>as above test 3 not hidden</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution will require the developer/cms to update both the HTML and javascript to make the hover work. That is not necessary unless the original HTML structure is unchangeable. But even if that is the case, it's still possible to achieve adapting javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

for opening:

```
$("#img-plaster").mouseover(function(){
    $("#plaster-nfo").show();
});
```

and to close by mouseout:

```
$("#img-plaster").mouseout(function(){
    $("#plaster-nfo").hide();
});
```

have a nice day :)